# How to implement Role Based Access Control with Authentication and Session Management in Struts2?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I would like to implement role based access control in my `Struts2.3` application to make it secure.

Below are the features I am looking for:

1. User Authentication and Session Management with Session Timeout.
2. Authorization on the basis of User role.

I have search a lot on this topic but not able to find a proper solution.

I have implemented Acegi security in `Struts1.2` applications but didn't find a proper solution to implement security in `Struts2.3`.

Any pointers on this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Spring security is the best way to go and i am not sure about your statement of proper solution, Spring security is independent of the underlying framework your are using

Answer (score 2):

`Acegi Security` is now called as `Spring Security` from 2007.

All your questions are answered [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.pdf).

The document runs multiple pages, so I will give you quick pointers about topics that you need to check

User Authentication: **Using other Authentication Providers**

Session Management: **Session Management**

Authorization: **Access-Control (Authorization) in Spring Security**

Answer (score 0):

Authentication :
           LDAP  Integration with Application server is the way to go

> download openDJ, set users and a single group, assign user to the group
>
> using glassfish as a example, set glassfish LDAP realm, let the realm
>      point to the ldap server
>
> config the glassfish.xml and web.xml. specify the directory based restriction
>     according to your ldap group, thus different ldap user can access different 
>     area of your web app
>
> create a secure folder, put all web pages in those folder expect the login page.
>
> the point is once a use login through keyword j_security_check, glassfish auth the ldap
>     allow you to access stuff in the secure folder
>
> drawback is ldap doesn't have permission concepts

User Permission :

```
       for well defined permission access. you have to implement on you own
```

a permission table holds all the permission activities

a user table you must have already

a role table define all the roles

role to user many to many relationship

role to permission many to many relationship

```
user <-->    role <-> permission
```

whenever you want perform a action for a user, get the current username

from session, then get a list of role this user has

then get the permissions user role has

then check against the action, see if you are allowed to do it.

this is just one way to do it. I would wish LDAP gives you ability

to define permissions , apparently it doesn't